# Svelte don't load components with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, components, svelte

I want to build an application with Node.js and Svelte, but when I try to import a component it wasn't load. 
Server side code:

```
const app = require("express")();
const http = require("http").Server(app);
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const fs = require('fs')
const express = require('express')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.write(fs.readFileSync('./pages/homepage.svelte', 'utf-8'));
    res.end();
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
   console.log('Utente connesso!')
});

http.listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Listening on *:" + port);
});
```

Homepage.svelte:

```
<script>
    import Component from './components/Component.svelte'
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="it">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>SocialTree</title>
</head>
<body>
    <Component />
</body>
</html>
```

Component.svelte code:

```
<div>
    <h1>Test</h1>
</div>
```

Thanks in advice and sorry for bad english!

Comment: You need to compile all *.svelte files into javascript, that's how svelte works. You don't just serve a svelte files. Here https://svelte.dev/tutorial/basics you can see at the top on the right an editor with some html and in the section bellow you see a result and JS output. The JS output is compiled App.svelte file.

Comment: @Molda thanks, but the file works if is one, when I try to import a component it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: it works with just your `homepage.svelte` because it's just html and css that your browser can interpret and render, you are just serving a static page at that point